# SQL Function not returning any value

Tags: sql-server

My SQL Server function is not returning any value.
Below is my script. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[PreviousService](@Order int)
RETURNS @rtTable TABLE
(
        OrderId Int,
        PreviousService Int,
        CurrentService Int
)
AS
BEGIN
Declare @PreviousService Int,
        @CurrentService Int

DECLARE @resultTbl table (OrderId Int,PreviousService Int,CurrentService Int)

Select Top 2 @PreviousService=II.ServiceId
        From InvoiceItems II 
        Inner Join Invoices I On I.Id = II.InvoiceId 
        Inner Join Orders O On II.OrderId=O.OrderId
        where II.ServiceId is not null And O.OrderId= @Order And I.InvoiceStatus = 20
        Order By I.CreateDate Desc
Select Top 1 @CurrentService=II.ServiceId
From InvoiceItems II 
Inner Join Invoices I On I.Id = II.InvoiceId 
Inner Join Orders O On II.OrderId=O.OrderId
where II.ServiceId is not null And O.OrderId=@Order And I.InvoiceStatus = 20
Order By I.CreateDate Desc

insert into @resultTbl
Select O.OrderId,@CurrentService,@PreviousService
From Orders O
Where OrderId=@Order
return;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't required the @resultTbl, you can insert into @rtTable directly

change the last insert statement to

```
insert into @rtTable 
Select O.OrderId,@CurrentService,@PreviousService
From Orders O
Where OrderId=@Order
```